# How to use the value of a 2d array as an index to a 3d array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 2d array, A, with shape (n x m), where each element of the array at position (i,j) holds a third value k. I want to increment a 3d array with dimensions nxmxl at position (k,i,j) based on the 2d array value and position.

So for example if

```
A = [[0,1],[3,3]] -> I would want B to be 

[[[1,0],
  [0,0]],

  [0,1],
  [0,0]],

  [0,0],
  [0,1]],

  [0,0],
  [0,2]]]
```

How do you do this in numpy efficiently?

Comment: Shows how you'd do this in-efficiently.  The action isn't obvious from your example and word description.

Comment: Your `B` has shape (4,2,2).  `A` values could be indices of the first dimension (4), but not either of the others.  Your problem might be easier if `A` was 1d, and `B` 2d.  The mix of 2 and 3d probably isn't essential.

Comment: @hpaulj, sorry, the first axis is implied from max value of the array, in this case 3.

Comment: OK, so `B[A,:;]` will work, producing a (2,2,2,2) array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is somewhat ambiguous, but if the intent is to increment some unknown array `B` at indices `(0,0,0)`, `(1,0,1)`, `(3,1,0)`, and `(3,1,1)`, then the following should be fine:

```py
B[(A.ravel(), ) + np.unravel_index(np.arange(np.prod(A.shape)), A.shape)] += increment
```

For example:

```py
A = np.array([[0,1],[3,3]])
B = np.zeros((4,2,2), dtype=int)
increment = 1

B[(A.ravel(), ) + np.unravel_index(np.arange(np.prod(A.shape)), A.shape)] += increment

>>> B
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [1, 1]]])
```

Another way of doing the same thing is:

```py
w, h = A.shape
indices = (A.ravel(),) + tuple(np.mgrid[:w, :h].reshape(2, -1))

# then
B[indices] += increment
```

Answer (score 1):

I can produce your `B` with:

```
In [208]: res = np.zeros((4,2,2),int)
In [209]: res.reshape(4,4)[np.arange(4), A.ravel()] = [1,1,1,2]
In [210]: res
Out[210]: 
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 2]]])
```

I use the `reshape` because `A` values look more like indices of

```
In [211]: res.reshape(4,4)
Out[211]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2]])
```

Comment: This is so cool. You got a different read of the question than I did (and yours might be the correct one), but I didn't know you could use `.reshape()` as an l-value. After years of usage, I keep marveling at how elegant and powerful `numpy` is.